# The project file could not be loaded for csproj

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0, asp.net-core-2.0

I migrated my .netcore 1.1 proj to 2.0 using this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/

but when i perform "dotnet restore -v d" i get the following error:

> ```
> Build started 10/23/2017 19:57:01.
>      1>Project "someproj.csproj" on node 1 (Restore target(s)).
>      1>Building with tools version "15.0".
>      1>someproj.csproj(1,1): error MSB4025: The project file could not be loaded. Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
>      1>Done Building Project "someproj.csproj" (Restore target(s)) -- FAILED.
>
> Build FAILED.
>
>        "/someproj/someproj.csproj" (Restore target) (1) ->
>          /someproj.csproj(1,1): error MSB4025: The project file could not be loaded. Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1,
> ```
>
> position 1.
>
> ```
>     0 Warning(s)
>     1 Error(s)
> ```

Here is the output for dotnet --info

> .NET Command Line Tools (2.0.0)
>
> Product Information:  Version:            2.0.0  Commit SHA-1 hash: 
>   cdcd1928c9
>
> Runtime Environment:  OS Name:     Mac OS X  OS Version:  10.12  OS
>   Platform: Darwin  RID:         osx.10.12-x64  Base Path:
>   /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/2.0.0/
>
> Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host
>
> Version  : 2.0.0   Build    :
>   e8b8861ac7faf042c87a5c2f9f2d04c98b69f28d

This is my csproj file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
    <Folder Include="swagger_static\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="2.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Logging" Version="1.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="1.50.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http" Version="4.3.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Threading" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="10.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
  <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0" />
  <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
  <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\..\recon.curator.common\recon.curator.common.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\..\recon.curator.service\recon.curator.service.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Try removing that first line in the *csproj* file. I have a new application that I create using a Core 2.0 template, and that line is not in the file.

Comment: Same issue after removing the first line.

Answer (score 2):

Turned out there were some special characters in the file which are not visible in VSCode. When i opened the file on Vim, it showed some unwanted characters....deleting those fixed the issue

Comment: Do you mind sharing what are the special characters that you deleted?

Comment: @AlexX. I had a similar problem, it looks like it was a UTF8 BOM character for some reason. Not certain.... anyway, you can tell VS Code to re-save the file using the Windows Western encoding and then save it back as UTF8 without a BOM. Fixed it for me.

Comment: same for me, changing the web.config to UTF8 (without BOM) fixed the issue